# Exception thrown when calling `Completer.completeError`

Tags: dart

Please compare the two following examples:

Example 1:

```
import 'dart:async';

Future<void> main() async {
  final c = Completer<void>();
  print(1);
  c.completeError(Exception("hello"));
  print(2);
  await c.future;
}
```

which prints

```
1
2
Failed to load ".../x_test.dart": hello
```

Example 2:

```
import 'dart:async';

Future<void> main() async {
  final c = Completer<void>();
  print(1);
  await (() async => c.completeError(Exception("hello")))();
  print(2);
  await c.future;
}
```

which prints

```
1
Failed to load ".../x_test.dart": hello
```

I thought that in the second example, the exception should be bound to the future of the Completer and hence also be thrown when awaiting for the future.

Is there a way to defer an exception with a Completer to a later point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I see when I run your second example in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/0c83ea762438b4ba949fe16bc1ed8f36?null_safety=true) is

```
1
Uncaught Error: Exception: hello
2
Uncaught Error: Exception: hello
```

The error is uncaught *twice*. That matches what is actually happening:

- You print `1`.
- You call `() async { c.complete(Exception("hello")); }()`. This schedules a microtask to
  complete the completer's future with the exception. Then the call returns another future and schedules a microtask to complete that future with `null`.
- Then you await the latter future.
- Then the first microtask runs and completes the completer's future with an error. At this point there are no listeners on the future, so the error is considered *uncaught* and reported to the root zone's uncaught async error handler. This prints the first uncaught error line.
- Then the second microtask runs and completers the other future. This makes the `await` complete.
- Then you print `2`.
- Then you await the completer's future. Since the future is already complete, this schedules a microtask report this to the await.
- Then that microtask runs and the second await completes by throwing the exception of the completer's future.
- That throw is uncaught and is therefore also reported as an uncaught error.

It's no entirely clear what you want. Do you want the completer's future to complete *later* (if so, how much), or do you just not want the first completion to be considered uncaught?

The latter is easier, just do:

```dart
  completer..future.catchError((_){})..complete(Exception("hello"));
```

If you pre-attach an error handler to the future, which handles (by ignoring) the error, then the future won't consider the error unhandled.
(Arguably, it would be nice to have a way to complete a completer with an error, and say up front that it shouldn't be considered unhandled).

Comment: I actually did run it on Dart on a Mac and looks like the behavior differs from web. On the Mac, the program exists after the first error.

Comment: Preattaching looks good. Actually I am using that construct in some testing environment where I ignore some exceptions to later (re)throw the first exception that happened. Just doing “throw e” looses the stack since Dart is missing a “throw e at stack”. So I am using “await Future.error(error, stack)” to propagate the original stack.

Comment: The uncaught-error behavior is different on the web. On native, an uncaught error can terminate the entire program. On the web, you cannot kill the page, so the program keeps running after the first uncaught error.

Comment: Good idea but pre-attaching gets esoteric when the future has a return value, especially a non-nullable one. The empty function in the example is then required to return a valid value of the future's type.

Comment: The stricter type system has definitely made this harder. You can use `.then<void>((){}, onError: ....)` instead of `.catchError(...)` to side-step that problem.